# Strange error message when I tried to log in to public wifi

Tags: kubuntu

I run Kubuntu and Lubuntu on bootable USB drives, and take both of these operating systems to public wifi hotspots. Lubuntu connects to the wifi with no issue, but on Kubuntu, I get an error message that says, "Access point does not support PSK, but settings require it" - and I am unable to connect to the wifi. What is the fix to this issue? Thank you.